# How to put the scores into 1st to last place in a msgbox? (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2015, basic

I have added the scores together and now need to sort them from 1st to last place in a msgbox how do i do that.

```
Dim total As Decimal
        If File.Exists("totals.txt") Then
            File.Delete("totals.txt")
        End If
        For intCount = 0 To (numGymnasts - 1)
            total = Val(strScores(intCount, 3)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 4)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 5)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 6)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 7)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 8)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 9)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 10)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 11)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 12)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 13)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 14)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 15)) + strScores(intCount, 16) + Val(strScores(intCount, 17)) + Val(strScores(intCount, 18))
            Dim Append As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("totals.txt")
            Append.WriteLine(strScores(intCount, 1) & "," & total)
            Append.Close()
```

Comment: It may be better for you to sort the scores before you write it to the text file. You could use ArrayList and sort your entries. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863601/sorting-text-file)

Comment: You'll save a lot of time if you open that `StreamWriter` before the start of the loop (i.e. before the `For` statement), and close it after the `End For`. Just keep the `Append.WriteLine` inside the loop.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to read the file of totals, sort them, and then display them?